# Почему не срабатывает прокрутка колесом мыши при попадании курсора на видео?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Для прокрутки я использую scroll-pane и mousewheel библиотеки. Вызывается скролл так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.content_in').jScrollPane({
     autoReinitialise: true
});
});
```

Все работает, но когда курсор при прокрутке колесиком мыши попадает на видео с ютуба, то прокрутка колесиком мыши перестает работать

Наглядный пример можно посмотреть тут https://jsfiddle.net/t4sw76zc/

Проблема наблюдается в браузере Firefox

Как это исправить или в каком именно скрипте искать решение?

Comment: Проверил ваш пример, скролл работает. В каком браузере наблюдается проблема? И не долистали ли вы до конца блока?

Comment: @VenZell в фоксе не пашет

Comment: Не воспроизводится и в Firefox: http://i.imgur.com/qjqWpQd.gifv

Comment: Проблема наблюдается в браузере Firefox

Comment: Есть идеи у кого-то?